# How can I completely dismiss a pop-up notification (instead of sending it to the action center)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, notifications, action-center

So in Windows 10 (currently on Enterprise 21H2 because this is a company computer), notifications appear as a pop-up. If I want to interact with the notifications, I can do that by clicking on the notification directly or on one of the actions that the notification gives me, if there are any. But if I want to just dismiss it completely, I can't find a way of doing that. A click on the X in the notification just sends it to the action center, meaning that I then have to go into the action center, and then click on the X again to completely dismiss it. Especially since I have a not so small notification stream coming in, this can get really annoying.

So, how can I just dismiss it entirely? I've seen keyboard shortcuts to dismiss it (oddly enough the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shortcut doesn't work for me, but even the articles suggesting it say that <kbd>delete</kbd> will then only send it to the action center). Some notifications have a dedicated Close action, but ironically enough, those are usually the notifications where I don't need it. Otherwise many instructions seem to point the user to turn off notifications completely, which is not the goal here.

Comment: You could disable the Action Center: in Settings, search for "Turn system icons on or off".

Comment: Problem is that then I can only see the pop-up notification, and if I get notifications when I'm away, there's no way of seeing them anymore. That would also mean I wouldn't have the possibility of leaving a notification in the action center to act on later if I want to (depending on the notification).

Comment: I do not understand why this is still happening and how there is no third party tool even to fix this.